# PHP Trying to Use a Namespaced Function (Not Class)

Tags: php, function, namespaces

I'm running PHP 5.6.24 and as far as I understand, I should be able to do this:

### functions.php

```
<?php
namespace lib;

function test_function ($var) {
    echo $var;
}
?>
```

### test.php

```
<?
require 'functions.php';

use lib\test_function;

test_function('Hello, world!');
?>
```

However, I get a Fatal error: Call to undefined function test_function()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you're not sure what version of php you are running go ahead and write a script that just has `phpinfo();` in it. and look through it.

Comment: I have PHP 5.6.24.

Comment: im pretty sure you have to give the file a namespace also.

Comment: Look at the first example: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: That page has nothing related to this question. I'm trying to import a function from another namespace using the keyword "use," which isn't even mentioned in that link.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: OK I read your link and found the solution was to add the word "function" after "use." After that, it worked! Thanks! If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use a function, you have to do something like this:

```
use function lib\test_function as func;
func("Hello World!");
```

Hope this helps!

[Supporting Link!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: That was it! I needed to add the keyword "function" after "use." Thank you!